# InfoWindow height incorrect when using tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [tabber.js](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/) to add tabs to my InfoWindows, and I use the following code to ensure that the tabs are rendered after the InfoWindow's DOM is ready:

```
infowindow.id = marker.markerid;
infowindow.open(map, marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    tabberAutomatic({div: document.getElementById(marker.markerid)});
});
```

With the Google Maps API, **the height of the InfoWindow is automatically calculated from it's content when the InfoWindow *opens***, not when the DOM is ready. The result is that the InfoWindow is roughly twice the size that it should be, because the height is basically the sum of the heights of all the content in each tab. When the tabs are rendered, I'm left with lots of whitespace in the InfoWindow.

So what I need to do is force the InfoWindow to recalculate it's height ***after*** the tabs are rendered. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQJJU/) illustrates my issue. How can I force the InfoWindow to properly calculate it's height in this situation? Explicitly setting a maxHeight or equivalent is not an option, because the contents of the InfoWindow are generated dynamically.

Comment: I guess the height of the **infoWindow** should be the size of the taller tab, or will the **infoWindow** resize based on the active tab? This sounds like a timing issue. I don't think you have to  force the InfoWindow to recalculate it's height after the tabs are rendered.

Comment: InfoWindow.SetContent() can apparently cause the size to recalculate.  Perhaps that could help?

Comment: Do you have an example of the page you're working on? I just revamped a ton of stuff on an intricate google maps integration, I might be able to show you the css for the info window if it relates to what you're experiencing.

Comment: @BrianNoah I have updated my question with a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @castillo.io I'll give these ideas a try.

Comment: @BenBarden Not sure this helps, because I'm already setting the content using the InfoWindow options.

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I have a chance. deadlines today.. :)

Comment: @GadyP. you're calling SetContent() again after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Actually no, but the answer from @castillo.io is using that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the issue by doing the following:

1. Declared the HTML content in the marker object by using the **'html:' property**
2. Created an **empty overlay** prior to setting the real content
3. **Updated** the Overlay content on click event and initalized the **tabberAutomatic** afterwards

You can see the live example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcastillo/af6bs/

**For multiple markers:**

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcastillo/Gk7AM/

Notes:

1. The empty overlay must be created **outside of the loop**.
2. There is **no** need to run the **tabberAutomatic** function on domready event.

Best,

Comment: This looks good for one InfoWindow, but I'm dealing with multiple markers, and in some cases I need to display multiple InfoWindows (one per marker)... I tried tweaking the code to handle this, but it stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/af6bs/2/

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover for multiple markers, please see my notes below.

Comment: This is great, and we're getting closer. But because you're using a single InfoWindow instance, you can only have one open at a time. I need to be able to have multiple InfoWindows open at the same time (one InfoWindow instance per marker).

Comment: This sounds like a separate issue. I suggest you open a new question regarding to that.

Comment: You're right. I'm marking this as the answer and I'll open a new question to deal with multiple markers.